JS Browser fetch expect 100-continue
I recently found out about this behavior of first sending the headers and the waiting for a 100-continue status from the server, then sending the body.
I want this behavior for a file upload feature and I found no code examples, instead some discussions about this topic in relation to fetch.
From what I've been able to understand: this behavior is not supported in browsers? or in fetch? If it is, can someone share a code example?

Browsers support this feature, but you wouldn't notice. Servers choose to emit this header. If your server does, fetch()/browsers transparently handle it.
